# Extract rows when a column value is not na in pandas dataframe

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, nan

I am trying to understand why I am getting NaN for all rows when I extract non na values in a specific column. This happens only when I read in the excel file. It works fine with the csv

```
df=pd.read_excel('q.xlsx',sheet_name=None)
cols=['Name','Age','City']
for k,v in df.items():
    if k=="Sheet1":
       mod_cols=v.columns.to_list()
       #The below is to filter on the column that is extra apart from the ones defined in cols. 
       #The reason I am doing this because I have multiple sheets in 
       #the excel file and when I iterate over the entire excel file, I want to filter on that additional column in each 
       #of those sheets. For this example, will focus on the first sheet
       diff=set(mod_cols)-set(cols)
       #diff is State in this case
       d=v[~v[diff].isna()]
```

```
d
Name Age City State
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN 
1   NaN NaN NaN NJ  
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN 
3   NaN NaN NaN NY  
4   NaN NaN NaN NaN 
5   NaN NaN NaN NC  
6   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

However with csv, it returns perfectly

```
df=pd.read_csv('q.csv')
d=df[~df['State'].isna()]
```

```
d
Name Age City State
1   Joe     31  Newark  NJ  
3   Mike    32  NYC     NY  
5   Moe     33  Durham  NC
```

Comment: Likely, the issue is that `v[diff]` is a **DataFrame**, while something like `df['State']` is a **Series**. The behavior of DataFrame filtering is _very_ different if you pass a DataFrame or a Series as a mask, even if that DataFrame has only a single column. (Under the hood a Boolean DataFrame mask is handled by df.where/df.mask)

Comment: @ALollz - Thanks. Never realized that v[diff] would be a DataFrame. Used a different approach to retrieve the required columns. Thanks